# JavaScript TV4 object valudation, NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Folks,
  I am trying to add a tv4 format, however, the following is not matching regex for whatever reason.

```
tv4.addFormat({
    'year': function (data, schema) {
        if (typeof data === 'string' && !/^(19|20)\d{2}$/.test(data)) {
            return null;
        }
        return 'Year must be between 1900 - 2099';
    }
});
```

Regex is supposed to match 1900-2099 for year validation.  As per : https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4

Thoughts? :)

Comment: Why do people use regex? It's so unreadable. Isn't it more obvious to convert to integer and range check it.

Comment: well... not really in that case.  we want to specifically fail unless the exact match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work better

```
tv4.addFormat({
    'year': function (data, schema) {
        var i = parseInt(data);
        if (i.toString() === data && i >= 1900 && i <= 2099) {
            return null;
        }
        return 'Year must be between 1900 - 2099';
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried use addFormat but seems no execute always get error `ValidationError: Invalid type: string (expected numberAndNaN)` would you see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105527/how-to-allow-nan-as-number-with-tv4-validate do i miss something